# Powershell - Trying to calculate the average of a csv file using a function

Tags: powershell, csv

Below you can see my code. I' trying to calculate the average line by line of my csv file. The only way I have been able to do this is by using it as an array. My question is, is there a way to pass each line through the function so that I don't have to create multiple functions?

The file looks like this:

```
V1  V2  V3
5   9   3
5   6   2
```

Script:

```
Function Average($a) {

        Foreach ($line in $a) {
            $total = [int]$a[0].V1 + [int]$a[0].V2 + [int]$a[0].V3
        }
        return "The Average is $($total / 3)"
    }


    #Variables

    $a = (Import-Csv "Document.csv")

    #Logic

    Average
```

Comment: Can you add a language tag?

Comment: Yeah sorry Ive been trying to find how to do that :x it's for powershell

Comment: Your current function only outputs the average for the last line - do you need results for the entire file? Or a result per line? Or just the last line?

Comment: @mat the entire file, I need an output for each line

Comment: @SkullNerd The answer I've posted outputs an average per line

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you! this is what I'm looking for. Although I'm still new at powershell, so I have no clue as to what is going on inside the function. Is there an easier form of code that I can put in the foreach? Bedankt voor alle hulp :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the properties of each line (without knowing their names) through the `psobject` reference:

```
function Get-CsvAverage
{
    param(
        [psobject[]]$Lines
    )

    # Loop through all lines of input
    foreach($Line in $Lines){
        # For each "line" object, loop through its properties
        $Numbers = $Line.psobject.Properties |ForEach-Object {
            # Attempt to cast the property's value as an integer
            $_.Value -as [int]
        }

        # Output the average for the current line
        Write-Output ($numbers | Measure-Object -Average).Average
    }
}
```

Then use like:

```
$CsvLines = Import-Csv Document.csv
Get-CsvAverage $CsvLines
```

For your sample input this would produce:

```
5.66666666666667
4.33333333333333
```

Comment: Thank you! this is what I'm looking for. Although I'm still new at powershell, so I have no clue as to what is going on inside the function. Is there an easier form of code that I can put in the foreach? Bedankt voor alle hulp :)!

Comment: @SkullNerd Geen probleem ;-) I'm not sure whether there's an "easier" way, but I've added some comments to explain what each statement is trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

if your data separator is a space in your file

Solution 1 :

```
import-csv C:\temp\test.csv -Delimiter ' ' | select @{Name="Average";Expression={[math]::Round(([Decimal]$_.V1 + [Decimal]$_.V2 + [Decimal]$_.V3)/3, 2)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2

```
import-csv C:\temp\test.csv -Delimiter ' ' | %{[math]::Round(([Decimal]$_.V1 + [Decimal]$_.V2 + [Decimal]$_.V3)/3, 2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 3

```
Get-Content C:\temp\test.csv | select -Skip 1 | %{$avg=0; $_ -split " " | %{$avg+=[decimal]$_};[math]::Round($avg/3, 2) }
```